# Value "AJ" cannot be assigned to a variable

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I am assigning a variable to a function and it works for all values except one.

I put the value, to test the remaining code.

```
Dim campaignGoal As String: campaignGoal = "AJ"
```

This code doesn't produce any assignment.

I restarted my computer. It happens only with the value "AJ".

```
Sub main()
    Dim asdf As String
    asdf = "AJ"
End Sub
```

What I am executing.
[image]

In the `End Sub` line the `asdf = "BK"` is already executed.
[image]

EDIT: Here you can see a comparison of tooltips and local window as Mathieu pointed out. Use the latter so that you will not struggle as happened to me.
[image]

Comment: So you're saying that the same code tested the same way works with any value except "AJ"?

Comment: I've not tried any value but yes. Anyway the assignation should be done I don't undersand why it doesn't take the value. It works on other computers xD

Comment: So what happens if you add `Msgbox asdf` as the last line of code in the `main` routine?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that precisely so I couldn't say.

Comment: When you are debugging in a breakpoint you have the value of all variables at that given point. The asdf stills shows no value but it outputs value which means it has. Mervelous VBA, really. But it's solved. It is assigning simply that the debugger is not working well. Thank you

Comment: They are if you pass them (you can try yourself putting a breakpoint in the End Sub) and I had the same issue with the code being splited.

Comment: The value is not assigned until _after_ the line executes. It won't show up in the debugger if you put the breakpoint on the assignment line.

Comment: Yes, and I know that so I am placing it in the following line (once the assignment is done). I debug in a daily base really is not about placing bad the breakpoint.

Comment: FWIW I've sometimes seen really odd things in VBA (and Word field codes) if a name/value is set as a Windows default value for something. Is "AJ" stored as a system setting for something? Or being used somewhere as a constant value in Excel? Anything like that occur to you?

Comment: That last screenshot *does* raise eyebrows and depict unexpected behavior - can you confirm that the locals toolwindow isn't showing the value when the tooltip is broken like this? I've deleted my now-irrelevant answer, this is a legit issue. (thanks for edit/clarifying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a debugger glitch (can't repro). The *locals* toolwindow isn't perfect either, but I suspect it might more reliably show the correct value - which definitely *is* correctly assigned.

Prefer using the *locals* toolwindow (View > Locals) instead of tooltips.

Comment: I do not have my computer in front of me (it happens in the one  of my work and i left recently) but I do agree that is a glitch for sure, my coworker doesn't have this problem. Tomorrow I will look at the locals toolwindow to confirm this. Thanks for all so far Mathieu

Comment: This glitch is worrisome, RD devs are looking into what 
could possibly be the cause (we'll need to understand the ins & outs of it if we ever want to enhance the VBE debugger!). One hypothesis is that the assignment might have been optimized away in the p-code, but not in the interpreted source.

Comment: In the locals toolwindow it appears correctly Mathieu. I will from now on rely on locals toolwindow instead of tooltips as you've pointed out. Thanks for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this just cost me an hour of pulling my hair out tonight, in December 2023. So this isn't fixed yet. My variable was "AJ5". Code line was
anchor = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Text

anchor was Dim'd as a string, and worked for every other string I tried it with.

If while running the debugger you hovered over the Activecell.Offset, it showed a pop up of "AJ5". but after the line of code ran, anchor read as "anchor =".
As detailed above, the value apparently DID store, but won't confirm it is stored in the debugger, even if I run a line of code that directly assigns anchor = "AJ5"

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35348198)