# Value being assigned to a variable is incorrect but showing correct value in immediate window in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I dont know what is happening I have a value "HLAIC 5" in one of the cells and I am assigning this value to a variable "sept_acct". But the value that goes in sept_acct is "HLAIC and not "HLAIC 5". But on doing debug.print sept_acct the value that i see in immediate window is correct "HLAIC 5".

I tried changing the value and noticed the following results:

i) when i changed the value of "HLAIC 5" to "HLAIC VL II" the value in sept_acct became "HLAIC VL.

ii) when i changed the value of "HLAIC 5" to "HLIC 5" then sept_acct showed the correct value i.e "HLIC 5".

```
sept_acct = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Account Identification").Cells(Acct + 1, 3).Value
```

in this `cells(Acct +1, 3)` has the value "HLAIC 5"

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Account Identification").Cells(Acct + 1, 3).Value
```

when i do debug.print it shows correct value.

Comment: Welcome to SO. How have you defined `sept_acct `? Is there any format in cell `Cells(Acct + 1, 3)`? What do you get if you do `Debug.Print sept_acct`?

Comment: You should use `.Value2` instead of `.Value`. This will avoid any errors related to the formatting of the cell.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - There is no format in that cell, and yes Debug.Print sept_acct shows the correct value which is "HLAIC 5"

Comment: @M.Schalk, I tried .value2 too but it didnt work, and there are no formats in that specific cell.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the `sept_acct` declaration? The `Dim sept_acct` line.

Comment: If you see the right value, then it's ok. When you say *But the value that goes in sept_acct is "HLAIC and not "HLAIC 5"* where are you seeing it?

Comment: @NishantTrehan So where do you encounter the incorrect output?

Comment: I think this is what is happening https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709965/vba-is-not-assigning-a-certain-value?rq=1